# Excel formula with loop and if condition

Tags: excel, loops, if-statement, formula

We have a laundry machine in the company with a maximum capacity = 100kg. Now, the target is to put always 100kg of clothes in order to effectively use the washing products (shampoo, etc.). The amount being put there differentiate around 100kg more/less. Laundry machine has several different regimes of washing. Now, I need to figure out a formula that would tell me (automatically) whether a certain regime of washing has more/less then 100kg.

I could easily tell, if an "x" result equals 90 kg (90-100kg gives me the result). Now, the problem is, that I get several results per day and sometimes the capacity used is 110, 90, 110,90 etc. Now, when I sum all the numbers up - I would get 400 (110+90+110+90) and by deduction from 400 -> I would get "0" and that would mean, that everything is OK, which is not.

Could anybody advise me?

I hope you get the point.

Thakns!

[Laundry machine issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8MG5.png)

Comment: It would help if we saw how your data is organized and what you would want as the answer.  You gave us what you do not want.  please [edit] your questions to add a mock up of the data and expected output.

Comment: Hey Scott, I had just uploaded a pic of my data. I hope it helps to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

While your average() for the set of data would = 100, your Max() for that same range would show 110 and your min() would show 90.